# Let $G$ be a group of order $8$ and $x$ be an element of $G$ of order $4$. Prove that $x^2 \in Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am quite a beginner in group theory, so I need to get my proofs checked.
Here's what I've done:

We know, that the center of a group $G$, i.e $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ [no proof required here]. So, the quotient group $G/Z$ can be considered.
Now, consider $x^2Z*x^2Z=x^4Z=Z=(x^2Z)^2$, which readily implies that $x^2 \in Z(G)$.

Is this all? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You did not use that $ord(x)=4$?

Comment: How does $xZ\cdot xZ=x^2Z$ imply that $x^2\in Z$? This holds for all $x$ in all groups. Yet, there are many groups where $x^2$ is not necessarily an element of the center. At some point you must use the facts that $x$ has order four, and $G$ has order eight.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. How does $xZ\cdot xZ=x^2Z$ imply $x^2\in Z$?

Comment: Hint: If $G/Z$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian (prove that if you haven't seen it before).

Comment: I have edited the body, is it correct now?

Comment: No. Still not correct. You aren't even trying to justify the claim $(x^2Z)^2=Z\implies x^2\in Z$. The claim is false in general. You need to use the fact that $G$ has order eight in an essential way.

Comment: can I proceed with the claim though? Is there any hope?

Comment: You have to prove that $xZ$ has order two in $G/Z$. One route is to prove that A) $Z(G)$ cannot be trivial, B) $G/Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic. There may be others.

Comment: Since the factors of $8$ are $1, 2, 4, 8$ and $o(Z(G))=8$ readily solves the problem. So, the rest of the cases are $1, 2, 4$.

Comment: A totally elementary solution is contained [in this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64419/11619). For the other route, see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1224416/11619).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76229/discussion-between-subhasis-biswas-and-jyrki-lahtonen).